# Use a VST plugin that's a .dll on Mac

Tags: macos, plugins, dll, sound-editing, vst

I have downloaded what I think is supposed to be a VST plugin, so that I may use it to analyse sounds in the creation of music. (A VST, or Virtual Studio Technology, is an effect [or VSTi for instrument], that alters sound.  VST files for Windows are .dll, for Mac they're .vst.)

However, when I download said file I get a zipped file which contains only a manual, and a dll file. Usually I get the files with the extension .VST, which I then add to my VST files, and the actual plugin with extension .conpoment, which I add to it's respective file.  However, I just got that dll file.

I know that this particular program works on mac, as I stumbled upon it via an online tutorial in which a guy was using that same program, but I can't seem take the necessary steps to the point where I can actually install/use the file.

Furthermore, I've tried downloading it from other sites other than the official website, but I always get the same contents.

Comment: you can post images to imgur or something and link them here.

Comment: Provide the tutorial that you followed.  Give us something so we can help you.  You upload the image, you are given a link, you remove the inline code and jsut provide the url itself.  You can do this at any reputation.

Comment: You don't use it yourself directly as the user, your application uses it for patches and the like, I'm guessing the file you downloaded is a patch to the said application you will need to copy it into the applications program directory but without proper guides as to what you have done, I wouldn't be able to advise you further. And the reputation system is supposed to encourage users to learn to DESCRIBE their issues with words first before just uploading a picture. it also deters spam posts as Ramhound has said. if you don't like the system don't use it...

Comment: We are willing to help.  But honestly I have no idea what your problem is, which is the reason a screenshot would help, and the reason I asked for the tutorial you read. Your title gives us no insight and I personally have no idea what "VST" is and its not exactly something I can do a google search for without getting literally a trillion results.  Just because I don't know does not mean I cannot help you with a little research on my part.  I shouldn't have said it was to much hassel, it was a knee jerk reaction, to your comment about how its to much hassel to provide us a screenshot.

Comment: Also it isn't too much hassle to link to the picture that you've uploaded it is only marginally more time consuming than uploading a picture straight to SO

Comment: As @ultrasawblade says, Macs don't use .dll files, so it looks like you got the Windows version. Knowing what the plugin is would help; as at least we could confirm it exists for Mac. [BTW, your premise that the .vst is some kind of link to the 'real' component is incorrect. .vst & .component are 2 different plugin types. .component is an AU plugin, for the likes of Logic etc]

Comment: What's the name of the plugin?

Comment: Please clarify this question by responding to the concerns raised in the comments—don't vandalize it. The question has a useful answer, so I'm not going to delete it, but you could get a more useful one if you just chose to explain what exactly you wanted to accomplish..

Comment: I think the problem here is quite clear, is there a way to use a .dll file from windows on OSX? Where do you see the `unclear` question?

Answer (score 3):

In FL Studio on Windows, you can put the .dll in the Plugins directory under Program Files, and it will appear in the list of plugins when the program is started again.  I think you can also put it in C:\Program Files (x86)\VST, there is a setting and it checks there by default.

So you'd have to dig into your sound program's settings and see where it is looking for plugins.  Mac [does not use DLL's](https://superuser.com/questions/228309/macos-dll-equivalent), though.  So it sounds like the plugin you've downloaded might be for Windows only.